# How do I initialize a list with items of another list?

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to initialize list2 (list of object) with each item of list 1 (list of string).

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of String) From {"a", "b", "c"}
Dim list2 As New List(Of Object) From {list1.ToArray()}
```

But this doesn't work. List 2 just contains 1 item: the array of list1.
How should this be done?

Comment: Why is list 2 a `List(Of Object)` - `Object` is rarely helpful in usage.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: List2 will be used to populate a combo box in a datagridview.

Comment: that does not require converting to Object. Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thank you. Actually, list2 will be getting new data from several different list1's at different times with varying data types, then in another form, list2 will be providing the data to reuse a multi-purpose combo box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `list2` using the constructor of `List(Of Object)` type.

```vb
Dim list2 As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)(list1)
```

Comment: Using op's shorthand: `Dim list2 As New List(Of Object)(list1)`

Comment: Worked great. Thank you!